# Adjective after the object - "when I will go home I will find my parents sad"

Tags: adjectives, sentence-choice

I need a piece of advice. Look at this two sentences:

> *I got a bad grade. As a consequence, when I <strike>will</strike> go home I will find **my parents sad**.*

Vs

> *I got a bad grade. As a consequence, when I <strike>will</strike> go home I will find **my sad parents**.*

Now, to my non native ear, the first sentence is better because moving the adjective "sad" after "my parents" gives the idea that my parents became sad because of my bad grade. Whereas, the second sentence fails to accomodate for this particular circumstance, and it seems that my parents are always sad.

What's your take on this?

Comment: My take aligns with your take.

Comment: Your non native ear is correct! The first version is "natural" for the intended meaning. It's just about *feasible* that a poetically-inclined native speaker might use the second form in this or a similar context. Perhaps to imply that even though the parents aren't *always* sad, they're more closely associated with that state than you might expect (maybe because by further implication they're excessively concerned about their child's academic success). But if you want to write normal English rather than quirky poetry, stick with your gut instinct.

Comment: Thank you J.R and FumbleFingers. Sadly, grammar books don't explain those nuances properly.

Comment: @GoldenAge: I'm sure that's not true - it'll just be that you don't know where to look. Syntactically the two constructions are totally different. The first version features a "deleted copula" (compare *I think you stupid* as a somewhat affected version of *I think you **are** stupid*). That's to say ***my parents sad*** is short for ***that my parents are sad***, whereas in the second example ***my sad parents*** is just a straightforward noun phrase.

Comment: Well yes. Probably I just don't know where to look at. Furthermore, the books I studied are not that good either.

Comment: In _When I go home I will find my parents sad_, "my parents" is direct object and "sad" is objective predicative complement of "found". Some people call "my parents sad" a 'verbless' or 'small clause'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good ear.

When "sad" appears before "parents", it modifies them directly.   Your parents may well be inherently sad.   They certainly seem to be *unrelatedly* sad.   When it appears after, it acts as an argument of the verb "find".   In this case, "sad" is what your parents are *as you find them*.   It's a condition related to that moment just as much as it is related to your parents.

In turn, the introductory prepositional phrase "as a consequence" relates the moment of finding to the bad grade.

The pattern here is *Transitive Verb / Direct Object / Predicate Adjective Object Complement*.